# How to properly get Http Request Path including virtual directory

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have app and I deploy it in separate vdir = "/web/". I have controller/action that I can get access by `http://address.com/web/{guid}`, I need to get path of the request, when I get it:

```
HttpContext.Request.Path.Value = /{guid}
```

but I expect:

```
HttpContext.Request.Path.Value = /web/{guid}
```

how can I properly get full path of url?

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Request.PathBase contains the vdir part of the request url, so it'll be set to /web. you'll have to combine that with HttpContext.Request to get the full path

Answer (score 0):

I've decided my problem with the following code:

```
HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery()
```